# select, confirm, close events of sap.m.SelectDialog are not triggered from the fragment

Tags: sapui5

I am working with sap.m.SelectDialog in xmlFragment where the functions on search, confirm and close events are not being triggered. See my code below and please let me know where I am going wrong.

fragment

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <SelectDialog
        title="Contract Items"
        class="sapUiPopupWithPadding"
        items="{ci>/contracts}"
        search="handleValueHelpSearch"
        confirm="handleValueHelpClose"
        cancel="handleValueHelpClose"
        multiSelect="true">
        <StandardListItem
            title="{ci>name}"/>
        </SelectDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

controller

```
    handleValueHelpClose: function (oEvent) {
            var aSelectedItems = oEvent.getParameter("selectedItems"),
                oMultiInput = this.byId("contract_itm_in");

            if (aSelectedItems && aSelectedItems.length > 0) {
                aSelectedItems.forEach(function (oItem) {
                    oMultiInput.addToken(new Token({
                        text: oItem.getTitle()
                    }));
                });
            }
            oValueHelpDialog = 0;
        },
        handleValueHelpSearch: function (oEvent) {
            var sValue = oEvent.getParameter("value");
            var oFilter = new Filter(
                "Name",
                FilterOperator.Contains,
                sValue
            );
            oEvent.getSource().getBinding("items").filter([oFilter]);
        },
```

parent View

```
<MultiInput width="10%" id="contract_itm_in">
```

I have also tried attaching the events to the Dialog. Unfortunately, it did not work.

BR,
Anusha

Comment: Could you please share the part where the fragment is created/opened in your controller.

Comment: var that=this;     oModelContracts.read("/ContractItemsSet('" + sold + "')", {

     success: function (odata) {                  
 oValueHelpDialog 
 = sap.ui.xmlfragment("reports.view.fragments.valueHelpDialog", that);});

Comment: Did you check if the context you are passing to the fragment is actually the controller context? The fragment creation seems fine to me...

Comment: Hi Cmdd, Here the context is different, I realized the issue is here. I am attaching the valueHelpRequest function in selectedItem event of other Input item as The Multi input value help items are dependent on the value choosen in the other Input control. Now, I thinking of options to achieve the dependency between the two Input controls.

Comment: Okay Cmdd, thanks for motivating me to think this way, I found the problem and solution.

Comment: Please submit a short answer to complete this post.

Answer (score 1):

Please attach your dialog to your parent view to have the visibility of functions written in controller.

Example code below

```
this.getView().addDependent(oValueHelpDialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, Here i am trying to link two Input controls such that the value help of input2 is dependent on the value choosen for input1. so I attached the valueHelpRequest handler in the selectedItem event of Input1 which changed the context of valueHelpRequest function and all the functions related to the Input2. Realizing that, I removed the attachEvent in selectedItem and wrote a condition in valueHelpRequest to check if the Input1 is filled.

Thank you all,